# Add send date to HTML mail in TYPO3 powermail

Tags: typo3, powermail

Is it possible to add the send date to the HTML mail which is sent?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use the mail variable like `{mail.crdate}` in RTE or in HTML-Template because the mail object is not yet persisted (saved) at the moment when the mails are sent.
Using a format.date ViewHelper as a Workarround should help: {f:format.date(date:'now', format:'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')}

Comment: You're absolutely right. There is a getter for crdate but crdate is not set at the moment when the mails are send because the mail object is not yet persisted. I would simply use a date ViewHelper with the value now: {f:format.date(date:'now', format:'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')}
That can be used in RTE or ReceiverMail.html